# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'hello' does not contain an equals sign

Tags: java, apache-commons, properties-file

I am currently using the Apache commons configuration library to write and read data from a file. I am able to save the key value pair colors=hello to the user..properties file, but when i try to read the value is get the below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'hello' does not contain an equals sign
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getProperties(AbstractConfiguration.java:625)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getProperties(AbstractConfiguration.java:579)
at com.code.prep.CommonsMain.readProperties(CommonsMain.java:21)
at com.code.prep.CommonsMain.main(CommonsMain.java:12)
```

The code is as below

```
package com.code.prep;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;

public class CommonsMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CommonsMain main = new CommonsMain();
        main.readProperties();
//      main.writeProperties();
    }

    public void readProperties(){

        PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration();
        try {
            config.load("user.properties");
            System.out.println(config.getProperties("colors"));
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeProperties(){
        PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration();
        try {
            config.load("user.properties");
            config.setProperty("colors", "hello");
            config.save("user.properties");
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The Jars in the class path are:

commons-configuration-1.9.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

user.properties contains

colors = hello
user = thejavamonk

Comment: What does your `user.properties` file look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not be using

```
config.getProperties("colors")
```

but

```
config.getProperty("colors")
```

"getProperties(code)" is looking for (multiple) lines in your user.properties file of the form:

```
code key=val
```

so it's expecting your code as it stands to have lines like :

```
colors foreground=black
colors background=white
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like library issue. Open your file and check whether the data is actually available. From you code it looks like you are doing -

```
main.readProperties();
//      main.writeProperties();
```

Why would there be any data unless you write it? Call `writeProperties()` method first and then read it back.